# How to have a select statement in HQL that will return all rows regardless of null values

Tags: xml, hibernate, hql

I have an object that contains a one-to-one mapping.

Customer.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="com.asi.shared.Customer" table="Customer">
    <id name="id" column="CustomerID">
         <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="customerName" column="CustomerName" />
    ...
    <one-to-one name="corp" class="com.asi.shared.Corp"/>
 </class>
```

Corp.hbm.xml

```
<class name="com.asi.shared.Corp" table="Corp">
    <id name="id" column="CustomerID">
         <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="customerName" column="CustomerName" />
    <property name="storeNumber" column="StoreNumber"/>
    <property name="corpCustomerId" column="CorpCustomerId"/>
</class>
```

I would like to run the following query and have all the rows in the costumer table returned.

```
    select customerName, id, support, corp.corpCustomerId
    from com.asi.shared.Customer ORDER BY customerName
```

However, it only returns the rows that have something in the corp table.  Not every customer will have something in the corp table, I don't mind having corp.corpCustomerId = null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select `customer.corp.corpCustomerId`, you're implicitely doing an inner join between both tables, whereas what you want is a left join. Rewrite your query as is:

```
select customer.customerName, customer.id, corp.corpCustomerId
from Customer customer
left join customer.corp corp
order by customer.customerName
```

Side note: your code would be more readable if you didn't have all these redendancies in the properties names. No need to call the property customerName. It's a property of the Customer class, so `customer.name` is sufficient. Same for `corp.corpCustomerId`, which would be easier to read as `corp.customerId`.